# NodeJS read file and write file successfully but on later read the file does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have the following interesting scenario in a Yeoman generator but I have to fall back on regular NodeJS file system operations.

In my case, I need first read and write a file that already exists on the file system. I read the file synchronously and I write the file synchronously.

```
function myFunction1(){

    let content = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', 'utf-8')
    // change content in here
    let newContent = content+"Hello World";
    fs.writeFileSync('filename.txt', newContent);
}
```

In a later step, I need to read the same file again.

```
function myFunction2(){

    let content = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', 'utf-8')

}
```

The problem now is that the exact same file doesn't exist either in the filesystem or the code can access the file.
If I comment out the call for `myFunction2` the file gets written to the file system.

However, I have a problem reading a file I changed before again. The question is:

1. Do I something wrong?
2. Is there anything I miss here?
3. Are there some workarounds my issue?

I sadly cannot refactor them to have just on call because of there different scenarios for writing and reading.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but there's an error in `myFunction1` and `myFunction2`: `let content = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', 'utf-8)`  <-- you forgot to close the single quote after utf-8

Comment: Are you using relative paths like in the example? Maybe the working directory is changing. Try logging `process.cwd()` before each read.

Comment: Sorry yes had some typos - I always use the same path to file I checked that by writing the path to the console.
The thing is that even the file in filesystem only exists when the first function gets executed.
Looks pretty wired to me.

Comment: If the file is indeed still there and you're using the exact same filename to read it, then the current working directory must be changing.

Comment: Yes but not when even the file path stays the same too.

Comment: Try checking the output of `path.dirname(require.main.filename)`. This is the scope of your current file. I suppose that given that the rest of your code has no apparent issues, you probably have insufficient scope.

Also, to avoid this in the future, try to use something along these lines: -
`path.dirname(require.main.filename).toString() + "/filename.txt"` for calling your file.

Comment: If this still isn't working have you tried using 'utf8' instead of 'utf-8' in the read calls and/or newContent.toString('utf8') when writing the file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have some typos and/or missing arguments in your function calls.

Try this:

```
function myFunction1(){

    let content = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', 'utf-8');
    // create new file content to test writeFileSync logic
    let newContent = content + ' something else';
    fs.writeFileSync('filename.txt' , newContent );
}

function myFunction2(){
    let content = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', 'utf-8');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not helpful just fixed some typos I had in the code above. Real code doesn't have these.

Comment: It was not just typos. You had a bug in your code. Your previous code was: `fs.writeFileSync('filename.txt')`. I added    `let newContent = content + ' something else';
        fs.writeFileSync('filename.txt' , newContent );` I thought it could actually solve your bug.

Comment: No thank you but only fixed typos. Thank you anyway. The other two above pointed out the same.